# Confused on understanding arrays for classes and object java programming?

Tags: java, arrays, input

I am suppose to write a test program to ask the user to enter the number of rooms, dimensions of the room and the price per square foot of the desired carpeting. Then display the total cost of the carpet.
I am unsure on how to input the data from the array into the two classes and then calculate the cost
any help would be appreciate! thanks!

here is my 1st class

```
  public class RoomCarpet
  {
     private RoomDimension size;
     private double CarpetCost;

     public RoomCarpet(RoomDimension dim, double cost)
     {
        size = dim;
        CarpetCost = cost;
     }

    public double getCarpetCost()
    {
       return CarpetCost;
    }

    public RoomDimension getSize()
    {
       return size;
    }

    public void setCost(double CarpetCost)
    {
      this.CarpetCost = CarpetCost;
    }
    public void setSize(RoomDimension size)
    {
     this.size = size;
    }

   //calculate total cost
   public double getTotalCost()
   {
     return size.getArea() * CarpetCost;
   }

  //display the total cost
   public String toString()
   {
     String str = "Total Cost: " + getTotalCost();

     return str;
   }


   }
```

second class

```
 public class RoomDimension
 {
   private double length;
   private double width;

   public RoomDimension(double len, double wid)
   {
      length = len;
      width = wid;
   }

   public double getLength()
   {
      return length;
   }

   public double getWidth()
   { 
     return width;
   }

   public void setLength(double length)
   {
      this.length = length;
   }

   public void setWidth(double width)
   {
      this.width = width;
   }

   //calculate the area of dimensions
   public double getArea()
   {
     return length * width;
   }

   //print out length, width, and area
   public String toString()
   {
      String str = "Length: " + length +
               "\nWidth: " + width + 
               "\nArea: " + getArea();

     return str;
   }
```

Test Class (HELP!! :( )

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.io.*;

    public class TestProgram
    {
     public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         int roomNumber;
         double length;
         double width;
         double cost;

  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("How many rooms are there in the house? ");
  roomNumber = keyboard.nextInt();

  RoomDimension[] rooms = new RoomDimension[roomNumber];

  for(int index = 0; index < roomNumber; index++)
  {      

     System.out.println("Enter the length of the room " + (index+1) + ": ");
     length = keyboard.nextDouble();

     System.out.println("Enter the width of the room " + (index+1) + ": ");
     width = keyboard.nextDouble();

     System.out.println("Enter the cost per square feet " + (index+1) + ": ");
     cost = keyboard.nextDouble();          
  }

  }


  }
```

Comment: You want to create an array of `RoomCarpet` objects, based on user input.  So you already get the `length`, `width` and `cost`, can you figure out how to convert that into a populated `RoomCarpet` object?  Once you have that, add it to your array.

Comment: any example would help greatly thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So you mean using the args parameter that is in the main method?.
Well, you can define an input like this:

> Room-WidthXLength-Cost

Then you can use [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) to split the args:

```
for(String arg:args){
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("-");
    int rooms = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
    String dimmensions = st.nextToken();
    double width = Integer.parseInt(dimmensions.substring(0,dimmensions.indexOf("X")-1));
    double length = Integer.parseInt(dimmensions.substring(dimmensions.indexOf("X")+1,dimmensions.length));
    double cost = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());

    //pass parameters to the classes and then execute your method
    RoomDimension dim = new RoomDimension (length, width );
    RoomCarpet carpet = new RoomCarpet(dim, cost);
    System.out.println("Total cost: "+ (rooms * carpet.getTotalCost()));

}
```

I know there are better ways to do this like using regexp but I'm so versed with it. Also regexp will allow you to validate your input.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in your main method, after first extracting your constants - that is

```
// Constant questions.
private static final String HOW_MANY_ROOMS = "How many rooms are there in the house? ";
private static final String HOW_LONG = "Enter the length of room #%d: ";
private static final String HOW_WIDE = "Enter the width of room #%d: ";
private static final String HOW_MUCH = "Enter the cost per square foot for room #%d: ";

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  try {
    System.out.println(HOW_MANY_ROOMS);
    int roomNumber = keyboard.nextInt(); // got the room count.

    RoomCarpet[] carpets = new RoomCarpet[roomNumber]; // carpet array.

    for (int index = 0; index < roomNumber; index++) {
      System.out.printf(HOW_LONG, 1 + index);
      double len = keyboard.nextDouble();

      System.out.printf(HOW_WIDE, 1 + index);
      double wid = keyboard.nextDouble();
      RoomDimension dim = new RoomDimension(len, wid);

      System.out.printf(HOW_MUCH, 1 + index);
      carpets[index] = new RoomCarpet(dim,
          keyboard.nextDouble());
      System.out.println(carpets[index]);
    }
  } finally {
    keyboard.close(); // Close your scanner.
  }
}
```